# Why doesn't Java have macros?

Tags: java, c, variables, language-agnostic, macros

In class the prof said one reason he likes C better than Java is that C has a preprocesor, and in particular macros. Is there any benefit to macros over declaring a`final`/`const` variable with the desired value? I know Java doesn't have global variables so would there ever be a situation where using a variable in substitution for macros would not work?

Comment: One reason I like Java better than C is that there is no need for preprocesing.

Comment: @Celeritas: you're already pushing it for SO by asking about macros in Java, but asking for why Java gets a bad rap (a very non SO oriented question, which focuses on implementation related issues..) probably isn't appropriate and would be better left to programmers stackexchange.

Comment: IMHO, Much of the popularity of Java is that you can relatively easily understand most of its features and most of its gotchas because there it has less features than other popular languages. This make reading and understand some one else code much easier.  While there are still plenty of ways to write poor code in Java, that is made worse when you have many ways of doing the same thing.  For an experience developer this lack of options can be frustrating, but if you have to work with less experienced developers I still prefer to have less ways of shooting yourself in the foot. ;)

Comment: @MithrilRyu, there is *always* a need for preprocessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason you can't run your Java code through a macro preprocessor; it's just not done as part of the language.

With that said, most of the reasons macros are valuable in C are matters of the C language, and most people's use of them is extremely ugly and counterproductive, though they do have many good uses too.

Anyway, I would really question the expertise of someone who compares C and Java on the basis that one has macros and the other doesn't. In the big scheme of things, that seems to be one of the most trivial differences between the languages. Highlighting it suggests to me that the person does not understand the real differences between the languages; perhaps he likes C but doesn't know how to name any of the actual features C has over Java - things like storage duration and representation of types.

Comment: +1 for the comment about the teacher...  My complete speculation would be that this is something like an EE professor who made an off the cuff comment without knowing much programming..

Answer (score 5):

Using a macro system in C has been a long standing tradition that often leads to incomprehensible build chains, and very project specific build configurations.  I would argue that the reason that macros exist in C is to overcome the shortcomings it has as a language for when you need things that macros provide (for example, you can use interfaces in Java, which solve the problem of needing to make a "generic" instance of something).

Still, there are times when having a macro system just seems to fit a problem easier.  I do know of some shops that do this -- for example -- when they need to support multiple different versions of an API.  Generally you can overcome this problem in Java by proper use of interfaces and a good abstraction layer in your design.  However, there [are macro systems for Java](http://www.cybercom.net/~kimbly/jatha/) out there!  You can use them, if you please.  You might also note that, as far as macros go, C macros aren't really anything very special.

(In my opinion your teacher was somewhat off base...)

Comment: Your "answer" is more confusing than anything else...

Comment: @Asblarf so donvote it.  You don't provide any reasons for why my answer is bad, but if you think I really messed up, go ahead, I won't take personal offense to it, but I would suggest you explain why you think so rather than just giving a fairly insulting knock...

Comment: @Kristopher_Micinski I'm sorry. I didn't mean to insult. My point is that your answer is more a comment than an actual answer (i.e. a suite of arguments / examples). I'm seriously sorry.

Comment: No problem.. I try to provide a pointer as to why you don't need a macro system in C, which is because C lacks the expressiveness -- as a language -- that Java provides for abstraction.  There are patterns in C which emulate it and boost its potential.  I think that stands as a solid enough answer.

Answer (score 3):

Macros in C are not just global constants. They can also define functions, like

```
#define SHOW_DEFINE(x) printf("%s=%s\n", #x, STR(x))
```

This can be quite helpful during debugging. It is unfortunatly also easy to hurt yourself quite badly with Macros.

```
#define  MULTIPLY(X,Y)  X*Y
```

works fine for, lets say MULTIPLY(1,2) but leads to problems if one uses MULTIPLY(1-1,2-2) = 1-2*2-2 = 1-4-2  instead of the expected 0*0.

Usually, with modern tools such functions are not longer necessary and with a good design and some abstraction and the interfaces that Java provides it is in general not necessary to have macros in Java. Java is designed, afaik, to make it as hard as possible to shoot yourself.